# random number generator, android

Tags: android, random

Can anyone help? I need to generate a random number, and then

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tv1;
    Button bt1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                Random r = new Random();
                int i1=r.nextInt(80-65) + 65;   
                tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv1.setText(i1);
                break;};
        }
    }
```

And then it closes app after pushing button.

Comment: What did you see in the log files (`CatLog` rocks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
  tv1.setText(i1);
```

with

```
tv1.setText(String.valueOf(i1));
```

with `tv1.setText(i1);` you are looking for a String with id `i1`, inside `string.xml`. That `id` probably does not exists and will cause a crash for `ResourcesNotFoundException`

Edit: the `tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` inside the onClick is useless since you are performing the same initialization inside the onCreate. Also you can move `Random r = new Random();` inside the onCreate. Of course you have to keep `r` as class member

Comment: `tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)`; initialization everytime on button click can be removed and probably this `Random r = new Random()`; can be moved outside the button click

Comment: @Raghunandan you are right

Comment: i just mentioned so that you can add that also as part of your answer. by the way you were super quick to answer

Comment: Thank you. Forgot about that need to get string from.